# Inserting HTML to an SQL array using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to figure out an efficient way on how to format my SQL array data to include HTML formatting, which then writes to a file. I don't consider myself an advanced PHP user, so apologies if my code may not be the best approach. Currently I'm using:

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
$data = array($row["name"], $row["subject"], $row["date"], $row["var1"], $row["var2"], $row["var3"], $row["var4"], $row["var5"], $row["var6"]);
fputcsv($file, $data);   
fclose($file);
```

This works fine when outputting the text data I need to a CSV file, but would like to add HTML breaks, and other HTML formatting within each array.

I've managed to handle my issue using fwrite. Thanks for everyone's input and advice!

Comment: Is your goal to have styling when you eventually open your csv in excel? Or you just want to store the data in the csv without it breaking? If the latter, htmlentities('<h1>'.$row['name'].'</h1>'); should work

Comment: @scott Unfortunately, when I try that, I get "PHP Warning:  htmlentities() expects at most 4 parameters, 9 given". The reason why I chose to use fputcsv is because it doesn't write any array keys. My end goal is to grab SQL data, format it with HTML, and save to HTML file to be used later via browser/email.

Comment: First off, the `fputcsv` should probably be inside the `while` loop as well. That said, the snippet of code @scott gave you is for a single column only. If you want that for all 9 columns, you'll have to repeat it 9 times. Of course, if you want the same treatment for all of them, iterating iver the columns would be preferrable. You might get better answers if you give a small example of what the query result looks like, and what the corresponding CSV should look like.

Comment: yes, dont htmlentities on the array, apply it to the strings

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to handle my issue using fwrite. Thanks for everyone's input and advice!